# when i want to print my ticket with epson TM T20, i can print my ticket but exception status err_illegal to affich

Tags: android

I am working on a project where I implement epson android sdk
the problem is that:
I can print a ticket with the epson TM T20 printer, but an illegal error has been generated with the err_illegal status thereafter.
I can not find the solution, please help me if anyone has the solution.

Comment: Please add the code you have so far an where the error occurs.

Comment: This is my code where to find the error status: ERR_ILLEGAL

public  boolean connectPrinter() {
        boolean isBeginTransaction = false;

        if (mPrinter == null) {
            return false;
        }
       try {
            mPrinter.connect(MainActivity.targets, Printer.PARAM_DEFAULT);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            ShowMsg.showException(e, "connect", mContext);
            return false;
        }

Comment: //////// follow
        try {
            mPrinter.beginTransaction();
            isBeginTransaction = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            ShowMsg.showException(e, "beginTransaction", mContext);
        }
        if (isBeginTransaction == false) {
            try {
                mPrinter.disconnect();
            }
            catch (Epos2Exception e) {
                // Do nothing
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

Comment: Please update the answer with the code. It's unreadable in the comments